# Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am learning to create a task. But, I get below error:

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project xgiE0woXl2wo2zTZqMIV.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:190:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Some code snippet:

```
const task = {
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: "POST",
    url: "https://location-project.cloudfunctions.net/function-name",
  },
};
task.scheduleTime = {
  seconds: 60 + Date.now() / 1000,
};
const payload = {
  data: data,
};
if (payload) {
  task.httpRequest.body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString(
    "base64"
  );
  task.httpRequest.headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  task.httpRequest.oidcToken = {
    serviceAccountEmail:
      "project-123@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  };
}
const parent = client.queuePath(
  "project",
  "location",
  "queue"
);
const request = { parent: parent, task: task };
const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);
```

I am not very sure whether the error is derived from this line:

```
const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you running this code in Cloud Functions? Which IAM roles does the service account have in the project IAM bindings?

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, yes I am running it in Cloud Functions. The service account has "Cloud Functions Invoker" in the project IAM bindings.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference-access-control

Comment: @JohnHanley Did I misunderstand? I changed the service account in the project IAM bindings from "Cloud Functions Invoker" to "Cloud Tasks Admin" but still encountered problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the correct service account? Normally, the service account assigned to a function does not have the Functions Invoker role.

Comment: @JohnHanley, it seems I misunderstood. Actually, what information do you want to bring me?

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Read the link in my previous comment so that you understand how to set up permissions.